# WP7 passing multiple pieces of data between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app I am building my own media player. When a user selects a song to play want to be able to pass the link to the sample media and the metadata associated with it (Artist, Track, Album Art, etc.) The part I'm stuck on is how to group all the data and pass it to the media player page. Here's what i have so far.

Determine what item was selected and add data to query string.

**UPDATED**

```
    public void musicSampleSelectedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Track selected = (sender as Image).DataContext as Track;
        ListBoxItem pressedItem = this.listReleaseMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selected) as ListBoxItem;
        if (pressedItem != null)
        {
            string _rT = selected.title;
            string _rN = selected.release.name;
            //string _rA = selected.artists; ????
            string _rI = selected.images.large.url;
            string _rS = selected.sampleUrl;

            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MediaPage.xaml?releaseName=" + _rN + "&releaseTrack=" + _rT + "&releaseImage=" + _rI
                + "&releaseSample=" + _rS, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

OnNavigatedTo method to pull data out of the query string

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string releaseName = String.Empty;
        string releaseImg = String.Empty;
        string releaseUrl = String.Empty;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("releaseUrl", out releaseUrl))
        {
            sampleMedia.Source = new Uri(releaseUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I can use the query sting to pass multiple pieces to the media player, or if I to do something different to pass the data to the other page. All of my data comes from the web using a webclient. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueryString` is just a Dictionary of the parameters passed in via the Uri. The Uri uses the standard syntax of passing in parameters delimited by `&`.  So in your example, if you had something like:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MediaPage.xaml?releaseUrl=" + releaseUrl + "&releaseImg=" + releaseImg , UriKind.Relative));
```

then you can then parse this out using something like:

```c#
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("releaseUrl", out releaseUrl))   
{   
    sampleMedia.Source = new Uri(releaseUrl, UriKind.Absolute);   
} 

if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("releaseImg", out releaseImg))   
{   
    // do something with releaseImg
}
```

Comment: Also, you can find the documentation on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. I forgot that `Artists` is a collection within the `Tracks` class. How would i get that data so i can pass it to the next page, especially if there is more than one artist? see my updated code above. thanks

Comment: From the MSDN docs on the NavigationContext class, you'll see that the QueryString property is a Dictionary<string,string>.  So you could construct yet another string that represents the artists collection (like make it a comma delimited string) and pass that as a parameter. The alternative would be to use some sort of shared state in your application to pass the entire Track object around. For example, creating a SharedTrack member of your App class that holds the current Track. Take a look at Petzold's free book http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html.